# How do I stop octave plots hanging with line editing turned off?

Tags: octave

I'm using Debian Jessie and GNU Octave, version 3.8.1

If I run octave with the --no-line-editing switch on, to avoid using readline

```
$ octave --no-line-editing
```

and execute this command,

```
>> t=0:1; plot(t);
```

then the plot window hangs. Without the line editing switch it's ok.

Does anyone know how to work around this, or how to report the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been reported as [Debian Bug #675509](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=675509) and [Octave bug #37795](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?37795) so you don't to report this bug again.

You can use gnuplot: just execute `graphics_toolkit gnuplot` before any plotting or add it to your .octaverc to get it eexecuted everytime you start octave.

Comment: Nice workaround, thanks. gnuplot plots aren't as nice, but they work under emacs. If I want pretty then I can run in a terminal. I'm a bit amazed that the gnu people don't run octave under emacs!